# Can I make an ajax request locally and than send the response to the internet?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, server

I'm having a bit of problem here. Imagine I have 2 servers here locally "Server A" and "Server B".

"Server A" is accessible for the internet, "Server B" isn't.

I have a javascript file in "Server A" (accessible for the internet) which makes an ajax request (POST) to "Server B". Will people that make an request from "Server A" also receive the response from "Server B"?

If it isn't is it in anyway possible?

Thanks

Comment: and you will send the response to server A that will ultimately send the response to server B..??

Comment: This question is [too broad](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: What you're looking for is a proxy that goes through Server B, you could configure apache on Server B to do this so Server A's traffic gets forwarded.

Comment: Paradoxis is right ;)

Comment: @MaxBumaye I made my apache a reverse proxy.

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to make Ajax to server B which is not accessible from Internet. You have to make ajax to **Server A** and then **Server A** connect to **Server B** By **PHP CURL** for example

Comment: Why not?! You can make an internal HTTP request in something like an INTRANET?! Run server A & B in the same network and just expose server A?! You guys seem a bit clueless

Comment: Eventually i made na reverse proxy in apache.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Ajax requests do not come from the server. They come from the client.

If you want to expose data on B to the Internet, then you would need the Ajax request to be made to A and then have A proxy the data from B.

Comment: @MaxBumaye — No, it isn't. You can't make an Ajax request to a server that you can't reach. That is why you need to proxy. This is the same suggestion that Halayem Anis is making.

Comment: @quentin read my post and understand it! Just because it cant be reached through the internet, doesnt mean you cant reach it through your local network where server A could also be placed in?!

Comment: @MaxBumaye — Please read the original question and understand it. It is asking about Ajax from a client connecting over the Internet. The client cannot reach server B. The third paragraph of this answer describes a workaround.

Comment: @Quentin Well, I understand his question and what he is talking about is some kind of proxy setup. Your simply wrong with your assumption. Ajax is just asynchronous javascript... so talking about http requests in javascript you could to that on Node.Js :D

Comment: @MaxBumaye — No. That question is asking if Ajax can access a server that can be accessed from the server serving the page, even if the browser couldn't access that server. (It can't, which is why you need a proxy). Ajax is not "asynchronous javascript", it is "making an HTTP request without leaving the page". You can't do that with Node, because Node doesn't deal with webpages.

Comment: 1. Well if it is actually the served file that should do the ajax request to the "local" server you are absolutly right. BUT I understand his question differently, because the above wouldnt make sense. 2. Ajax just describes the concept of asynchronous datatransfer and this CAN be done by a node server. My server also communicates with the FB REST API asynchronously, so dont tell me this is not possible! :D

Comment: @Quentin okay in connection with the term AJAX he does seem to want to transfer data to the local server from a served "html" page - you are right. I retreat

Comment: Eventually i made na reverse proxy in apache.

Answer (score 1):

You could run a IAAS server EC Instance for example on Amazon (AWS) Set up a node.js Server to a certain port e.g. 8080 which is exposed to the internet and people could communicate with... you could set up another node.js server on this same instance that connects to a Port which you dont expose and access this via localhost.

Sending HTTP Requests from server to server can be done.